# How to add additional PostScript commands in PS files

Tags: c#, printing, ghostscript, postscript

My requirement is to add additional setpagedevice commands (eg: staple, punch, etc) like the below in a PS file.

```
**</Staple 3> setpagedevice**      % Start the first subset to be stapled
%Page 1
%Page 2
%Page 3
**</Staple 0> setpagedevice**     % End the first subset
**</Staple 3> setpagedevice**    % Start the second subset to be stapled
%Page 4
%Page 5
%Page 6
%Page 7
**</Staple 0> setpagedevice**     % End the second subset
```

I've to do this operation in a C# application. I would like to know whether there are any existing libraries that will allow me to insert setpagedevice commands in a PS file based on the specified page numbers. For example, I should be able to insert a staple setpagedevice command after 10th page in a PS file.

Comment: Why not use an existing library that can parse, manipulate, and save PostScript files?

Comment: PostScript is a programming language, you can't just stick pieces of program code into an existing program without some idea what you are doing. If the program conforms to the Adobe Document Structure Convention then you could look for the %%Page: comment and modify the file that way. Alternatively you could run the PostScript file as input to Ghostscript and use the ps2write device to produce a new PostScript program, you could probably use the PSPageOptions switch to include the specified program fragment on the specified pages.

Comment: The PostScript fragments look wrong. It should probably be more like `<</Staple 3>> setpagedevice` (doubled angle brackets, no asterisks).

Comment: @Dai My question is exactly that. I would like to know whether any such libraries exist. If you know any, please let me know.

Comment: @luserdroog You are right. The asterisks were added by Stackoverflow when I made it bold. Coming to my original query, are you aware of any existing library than can modify PS files based on our input? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@KenS 's comment has the answer which I was looking for.

If the program conforms to the Adobe Document Structure Convention then you could look for the %%Page: comment and modify the file that way. Alternatively you could run the PostScript file as input to Ghostscript and use the ps2write device to produce a new PostScript program, you could probably use the PSPageOptions switch to include the specified program fragment on the specified pages